# Anylogic, mutate the capacity of the resource dynamically

Tags: simulation, anylogic, event-simulation

I have a model with a queue and two machines, one of which is used just in case of overcrowding of the queue in front of these resources. 
My model has a simple Queue and a Delay block and I tried to mutate the Delay capacity based on a previous queue length using a function like this (written in Delay block capacity text field):

```
    if (queue.size() > 5) 
      return 2;
    else
      return 1;
```

But it doesn't seem to work... is it possible to change the number of resources dynamically based on a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the capacity value in the delay block is only considered in the beginning of the simulation, so it can only be considered as the initial value...

To change the capacity later, you can put some code in the on enter and on exit of the queue block:

```
delay.set_capacity(queue.size() > 5 ? 2 : 1);
```

Something like that.

Comment: Wow! Felipe you are a master! Thanks for your advices

Comment: Hi, Felipe, thanks very much for your solution. Since I need to change the capacity of a PedWait agent, similar to the question. However, I wonder to know how can I get all the enabled method for Agent like PedWait? When I check for the Anylogic  help document, I can't find the method `set_capacity`. Does this is a convention?  like `set_<parameter_name>()`, or there is some other document for developer?

Comment: set_capacity is clearly shown in the help documentation on the pedwait, look a bit closer... Ctrl F "capacity"... and you will find it